# Who is Peter in "Pride Before the Fall"?

Tags: andromeda

In the Andromeda episode "Pride Before the Fall" Beka meets someone who identified himself as Peter.

Throughout the episode we're led to believe he's a time traveller who will one day create the Nietzschean race from his and Beka's DNA. At the end of the episode it's (very heavily) implied that he's Drago Musevini. This is backed up on the [Andromeda wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Andromeda_episodes) where it says:

> Peter was Drago Musevini, the progenitor of the Nietzschean race.

However at the time I read the All Systems University website and believed that Paul Musevini created Drago as the first Nietzschean. Which suggests that it was in fact Paul who Beka met.

Who did the crew encounter? Was it Peter, Drago or someone entirely different? Could Drago have been both the first Nietzschean and the creator of the Nietzscheans?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drago was the son / clone of Paul.

http://andromeda.wikia.com/wiki/Nietzschean

> Drago Museveni, the clone/son of Dr. Paul Museveni, was born in CY
>   8403 (It is revealed later in the series that Drago had actually time
>   traveled to the future to obtain the DNA of Beka Valentine in order to
>   further enhance the Nietzschean race). Drago's children were the first
>   true Nietzscheans born, the result of genetic modifications. Because
>   of his influence, the first Pride was formed: Pride Museveni. Drago
>   had a philosophy all future Nietzscheans would come to emulate(most of
>   which was taught by Rhade). Due to the modifications of their genetic
>   codes, they developed three bony spikes called "bone blades" on each
>   forearm.

Drago is said to be the first Homo Sapien Invictus and he is the creator of the first true Nietzscheans according the research.

http://andromeda.wikia.com/wiki/Drago_Museveni

> Born in the year C.Y.8402 Drago Museveni was bio-engineered by his
>   father Dr. Paul Museveni, and the first Homo sapiens invictus.
>
> To ensure the superiority of his people, Drago Musevini time-travelled
>   through the Route of Ages and reached the Seefra System, where he met
>   Beka Valentine. Impressed with her, he stole a sample of her DNA,
>   after a one-night-stand. Afterwards Drago would devise a test for
>   Beka, stating that he had apparently placed a bomb within the ship
>   should she land or attempt to contact anyone (this would later prove
>   to be false) to test Beka's survival instincts for his future race.

So yes it is possible that Dragon was the "first Nietzschean and the creator of the Nietzscheans".

It's also stated here in the synopsis of the episode Pride Before the Fall.

http://andromeda.wikia.com/wiki/Pride_Before_the_Fall

> The crew is on the command deck of Andromeda with everyone at their
>   station, watching Peter’s ship escape through the Route of Ages. Dylan
>   tells Beka that Peter was actually Drago Museveni and she is the
>   blueprint for their race. If they ever get back to their universe and
>   resume the old fight, she will never be attacked since she is the
>   Alpha Matriarch. With the ship returned to full power and all its
>   former glory, they probably can get back, but Dylan has left command.
>   He is looking at Drago’s hidden coffin and finds the bones of his
>   vanquished enemy resting where they should be.

Also on the IMDB for the actor who played "Peter"

http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0613147/

> Andromeda (TV Series)  Drago Museveni
>   - Pride Before the Fall (2005) ... Drago Museveni

You can watch the full episode on Youtube currently and it will show that the scene I mean.

At about 30:30 Dylan says "I know you're real name and I know what you'll become. A failure.."

At around 34:00 since Dylan was near killing him reality started going crazy, until Peter declared that Dylan won.

At around 37:00 Dylan tells Beka that she is the Alpha matriach of all Nietzcheans.  And the other guy goes wait but Drago is the father of all Nietzcheans and then Beka goes " So Peter is.." and Dylan nods and says Mmhmm.  So yeah Canon proof in the actual video showing that Dylan acknowledges that Peter is Drago Museveni.

Comment: Interesting, the original ASU http://www.saveandromeda.com/allsystems/lifeforms/nietzscheans.htm doesn't mention this. Is it possible it's been retcon'd by fans to explain the discrepancy?

Comment: @Liath - it's Wikia, so most likely it's a fan retcon. It'd be nice to see an answer actually based on canon.

Comment: Well it's true that the Nietz race was started by Paul because he created Drago which in then perfected the race.

Comment: DVK again most of wikia articles are not just fan retcon but are based on canon logic.  Since it's heavily implied that Peter is Drago then it can easily be infered that he is the progenitor of the Nietzscheans.

Comment: Also added some more stuff including the actor who played "Peter" is credited as Drago Museveni on the IMDB.

Comment: Also added the episode itself that shows lines portraying Peter as Drago, because as they state if Beka is the Alpha mom that means that Peter is the father of all Nietzscheans aka Drago.

Comment: @DoctorWho22 my personal theory is that when Robert Hewitt Wolfe left a new writer wrote the script from his notes with mistakes. These were then RetConned.

Comment: @Liath If you read [Coda](http://www.cyberspace5.net/agentrichard07/coda.htm), you'll see that the series went in a _completely_ different direction.  The only thing from the original plans that were kept were the Abyss and Trance's people, for which hints had already been inserted in Season 1 - although both were changed somewhat.  If notes were left, I don't think they were used.

Comment: So which is technically canon?  It seems to me that since they changed direction what's aired on the television show is canon and the stuff that the original writer wanted to do is fan fiction as stated in what Izkata linked?